# When are we satisfied with the performance of a classifier?

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix

I am training a multi-head classifier (based on Resnet18) for a multilabel classification task. The dataset I am using to train the classifier is noisy and to improve the accuracy for the worse-performing labels I am grouping classes by looking at the confusion matrix.

Is there a criterium to decide when the accuracy for a selected label is satisfying? I have been told that the accuracy should be above 80% but I cannot find a reference for that. Thanks!

Comment: Compare it to a baseline model, whatever that may be for your case, say a simple model or a model with very simple forecasts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222179/how-to-know-that-your-machine-learning-problem-is-hopeless)

Comment: Note that [accuracy is not a very good evaluation metric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).

Comment: What level of accuracy do *you* need?  Don't let some anonymous, forgotten stranger determine your goals for you!